# Check a checkbox after loading page

Tags: css, checkbox, web

I try to learn CSS by making a website
I fond on internet a code to display text on a Facebook chat style.
I just don't know how to make it always open when I open the page.
I tried to change the values of content of it don't seems to work...

Here is the link : http://js fiddle.net/tovic/dUgHe/

Sorry or my bad English, and thx for the responses !

Answer (score 3):

JQuery!, May be usful:

```
if ($("#some-box").is(':checked')){
    //some actions
}
```

from: [Check if checkbox is ALREADY checked on load using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452033/check-if-checkbox-is-already-checked-on-load-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Please use jquery function for page load after check box checked

Comment: I think you need check box checked forever.am I correct